# Yii: Change default order in CGridView

Tags: yii, frameworks, cgridview

I have generated giix crud for model **Faq**

**Controller:**

```
public function actionAdmin() {
    $model = new Faq('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();

    if (isset($_GET['Faq']))
        $model->setAttributes($_GET['Faq']);

    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

**View - admin:**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'faq-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(array('order'=>'order ASC')),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'order',
        'question',
        'answer',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I want order items by field 'order', so I add 
`array('order'=>'order ASC')`
to `$model->search();` but this didn't change anything. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

update your search() function in the model and add the following code

```
'criteria'=>$criteria,
//add here

'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'order ASC',
),
```

and inside admin view change the dataprovider to this

```
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
```

Answer (score 5):

get CActiveDataProvider

```
$dataProvider = $model->search();
```

and edit property "sort"

```
$dataProvider->sort = array(
  'defaultOrder'=>'order ASC'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the '**search($order)**' method you can put:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = $order; // $order = 'order ASC' in your example.

return new CActiveDataProvider(YourModel::model(), array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    // build your criteria here

    // $criteria->order = 'something'; would be needed if you did `find?()` to return ordered array

    // Because CGridView|CListView uses data provider ...
    return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                '*',
            ),
            // ... so you need to set the default order for order to work
            'defaultOrder' => array(
                'order' => CSort::SORT_ASC,
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```